# Is there a way to use value from field which is a collection name as value for 'from' parameter in $lookup (mongodb)

Tags: database, mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

*Mongo V5.03*

I am using Compass for building a pipeline. And I am stuck here.

collection: hello

```
{
    "_id" : "...",
    "collection_name" : "world"
}
```

collection: world

```
{
   "_id" : "..."
}
```

while building a pipeline with mongodb aggregation, to call another collection, we can use $lookup operator. Syntax of $lookup looks like this :

```
{
 * from: The target collection.
 * localField: The local join field.
 * foreignField: The target join field.
 * as: The name for the results.
 * pipeline: The pipeline to run on the joined collection.
 * let: Optional variables to use in the pipeline field stages.
 }
```

For one time use, I can directly write `{ from : 'world' , ...}`. But I want to do this instead `{ from : '$collection_name', ... }`  so that I can keep calling field value because that collection_names field is an array which I $unwind it.

**Comeon tips, suggestions, solution**

Answer (score 0):

We probably do not have method to `$lookup` from dynamic collection name as of now. However, **if we have already known all possibilities of the collection names**, we may use multiple `$lookup` to perform conditional `$lookup` and use `$setUnion` to join the lookup results together.

Here is an example of knowing all 2 possibilities, `world` and `foo`; syntax in MongoDB 5.0+:

```js
db.hello.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "world",
      "localField": "key",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "let": {
        c: "$collection_name"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$$c",
                "world"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "worldLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "foo",
      "localField": "key",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "let": {
        c: "$collection_name"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$$c",
                "foo"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "fooLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      collection_name: 1,
      key: 1,
      allLookup: {
        "$setUnion": [
          "$worldLookup",
          "$fooLookup"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vtRZQ34cNbl) for your reference.

Comment: This is one way. If we know there is only foo1, foo2, foo3 than this would work. But what if this number increases. What will you do then?

Comment: I would reconsider my schema design if that is the case. Such a increasing number for various `$lookup` sources seems an anti-pattern. If all the collections are sharing similar document structure, perhaps you can simply put them all into a single collection? If they are having completely different document structures, then you still need extra processing and handling for each cases anyway. So my suggestion is you need to figure out what you really want to do with your `$lookup` in your real use case.